# How can I add more to the code generated by Laravel Artisan?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I want to include some commented code above my resource controllers class declarations, ideally to be added when generating the controller using `php artisan make:controller MyController -resource`. Namely, I want to add the path aliases at the top of each controller file:

```
/*
Verb            URI                     Action              Route Name              desc
GET             /photos                 index               photos.index            Display a listing of the resource.
GET             /photos/create          create              photos.create           Show the form for creating a new resource.
POST            /photos                 store               photos.store            Store a newly created resource in storage.
GET             /photos/{photo}         show                photos.show             Display the specified resource.
GET             /photos/{photo}/edit    edit                photos.edit             Show the form for editing the specified resource.
PUT/PATCH       /photos/{photo}         update              photos.update           Update the specified resource in storage.
DELETE          /photos/{photo}         destroy             photos.destroy          Remove the specified resource from storage.
*/
```

This is purely a convenience example, but there have been other times when I want to add other stuff to the models and migrations I am generating with artisan. Can this be done? Would I need to recompile the artisan binaries?

Comment: Pretty cool question, these things could actually be made customizable by simply adding them to config and publishable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky but if you know how to find your way around the container you should be fine.

First you have to overwrite the `ArtisanServiceProvider` by extending the default one and change this method.

```
/**
 * Register the command.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function registerControllerMakeCommand()
{
    $this->app->singleton('command.controller.make', function ($app) {
        return new ControllerMakeCommand($app['files']);
    });
}
```

By doing this you simply allow yourself to assign a custom `ControllerMakeCommand` in the container.

Then you simply copy that class as well and change code you want.

In your case the stub file.

```
/**
 * Get the stub file for the generator.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getStub()
{
    $stub = null;

    if ($this->option('parent')) {
        $stub = '/stubs/controller.nested.stub';
    } elseif ($this->option('model')) {
        $stub = '/stubs/controller.model.stub';
    } elseif ($this->option('invokable')) {
        $stub = '/stubs/controller.invokable.stub';
    } elseif ($this->option('resource')) {
        $stub = '/stubs/controller.stub';
    }

    if ($this->option('api') && is_null($stub)) {
        $stub = '/stubs/controller.api.stub';
    } elseif ($this->option('api') && ! is_null($stub) && ! $this->option('invokable')) {
        $stub = str_replace('.stub', '.api.stub', $stub);
    }

    $stub = $stub ?? '/stubs/controller.plain.stub';

    return __DIR__.$stub;
}
```

And of course you have to copy the stub file and edit it according to your needs.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the `ArtisanServiceProvider` file, any leads?

Comment: You're right, I just noticed that it's being registered via `ConsoleSupportServiceProvider`, so you need to overwrite it as well. And that you can find it in `config/app.php`.